# wp_insert_term auto unique name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

When creating a new term in a custom taxonomy with wp_insert_term, i've noticed that name should be unique.
I get a wp error message if it is not :

```
A term with the name provided already exists with this parent
```

I would like a way to automatically check if name is already exist and append it if yes.

So check :

```
get_term_by('name', $term_id, $taxonomy);
```

and if term exists append the name.

but is there a way to auto this with WP ? Like WP does with slug ?
Why should the name be unique, don't understand as the slug is.

thanks a lot !

François

Comment: Not automatically but you can use [`get_term_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

Comment: Yeah, as above - just check manually and append a digit if a name exists. You're already manually creating terms anyway.

Comment: @dalbaeb It's not what i need because i don't want to have ugly title in my taxonomy. 
What i need is a way to have the same Name in the Taxonomy Hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

### EDIT

### [PART DEUX](http://askville.amazon.com/deux-part-speech-sense-carry/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=13424467) OR [PART DEUX](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=part%20deux) - The Dirty Sequal, The Term Saga Continues...

Before anyone read this section, I will urge you to read everything I explained in **ORIGINAL ANSWER**. `wp_insert_term()` does not allow duplicate term names in non hierarchical taxonomies or in hierarchical taxonomies within the same hierarchy.

From  comments to my answer, the answer from OP and from the OP

> What i need is a way to have the same Name in the Taxonomy Hierarchy.

There is a way to achieve this, lets look at how:

### CAUTION - caution - CAUTION - caution !!!!

I went with a modified class of the `wp_insert_term()` function. As I said, there are protection inside `wp_insert_term()` to avoid duplicate term names. What I have done is to get rid of this protection in order to allow duplicate names within the same hierarchy. You basically need to remove the name check section and then the section that delete accidental duplicates when the term is already inserted.

Because of this, this class will allow an unlimited amount of terms with the same name, so it should be used with **great care**. 100 accidental page loads will insert 100 terms with the same name.

Here is the class with a few notes

**NOTE:**

- This requires at least PHP 5.4.
- Although I ran a few test to check the class' operation, I have not run any complete test on this, so PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE, run this on a local test install first and verify everything properly
- The class can be improved and modified as needed. I might have mixed syntaxes and scrambled code. This is just a very basic backbone with only the essentials

Lets look at the code:

```
/**
 * WPInsertTerm class
 *
 * Class to insert terms into the db
 * 
 * If term names are identical, in stead of throwing an error like
 * wp_insert_term(), the function will add valid term meta_key
 * 
 * @author   Pieter Goosen
 * @version  1.0.0
 * @access   public
*/ 

class WPInsertTerm 
{
    /**
     * Arguments to hold defaults
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @var array
    */
    protected $defaults = [
        'alias_of' => '', 
        'description' => '', 
        'parent' => 0, 
        'slug' => ''
    ];

    /**
     * Arguments set by user
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @var array
    */
    protected $args = [];

    /**
     * Term to insert
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @var string
    */
    protected $term = null;

    /**
     * Taxonomy the term should belong to
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @var string
    */
    protected $taxonomy = null;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $term = null
     * @param string $taxonomy = null
     * @param array  $args = []
     * @since 1.0.0
     */     
    public function __construct( $term = null, $taxonomy = null, $args = [] ) 
    {
        $this->term     = $term;
        $this->taxonomy = $taxonomy;
        if ( is_array( $args ) ) {
            $this->args = array_merge( $this->defaults, $args );
        } else { 
            $this->args = $this->defaults;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Public method wpdb()
     *
     * Returns the global wpdb class
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $wpdb
     */
    public function wpdb()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        return $wpdb;
    }

    /**
     * Private method validateVersion()
     *
     * Validate the current WordPress version
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $validateVersion
     */
    private function validateVersion()
    {
        global $wp_version;

        $validateVersion = false;

        if ( '4.4' > $wp_version ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( 
                sprintf(
                    __( 'Your WordpPress version is too old. A minimum version of WordPress 4.4 is expected. Please upgrade' ),
                    __METHOD__
                )
            );
        }

        return $validateVersion = true;
    }

    /**
     * Private method validateTaxonomy()
     *
     * Validate the $taxonomy value
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $validateTaxonomy
     */
    private function validateTaxonomy()
    { 
        $validateTaxonomy = filter_var( $this->taxonomy, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        // Check if taxonomy is valid
        if ( !taxonomy_exists( $validateTaxonomy )  ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( 
                sprintf(
                    __( 'Your taxonomy does not exists, please add a valid taxonomy' ),
                    __METHOD__
                )
            );
        }

        return $validateTaxonomy;
    }

    /**
     * Private method validateTerm()
     *
     * Validate the $term value
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $validateTerm
     */
    private function validateTerm()
    {
        /**
         * Filter a term before it is sanitized and inserted into the database.
         *
         * @since 1.0.0
         *
         * @param string $term     The term to add or update.
         * @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy slug.
         */
        $validateTerm = apply_filters( 'pre_insert_term', $this->term, $this->validateTaxonomy() );     

        // Check if the term is not empty
        if ( empty( $validateTerm ) ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( 
                sprintf(
                    __( '$term should not be empty, please add a valid value' ),
                    __METHOD__
                )
            );
        }

        // Check if term is a valid integer if integer is passed
        if (    is_int( $validateTerm )
             && 0 == $validateTerm
        ){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( 
                sprintf(
                    __('Invalid term id supplied, please asdd a valid value'),
                    __METHOD__
                )
            );
        }

        // Term is not empty, sanitize the term and trim any white spaces
        $validateTerm = filter_var( trim( $validateTerm ), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        if ( empty( $validateTerm ) ){
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( 
                sprintf(
                    __( 'Invalid term supplied, please asdd a valid term name' ),
                    __METHOD__
                )
            );
        }

        return $validateTerm;
    }

    /**
     * Private method parentExist()
     *
     * Validate if the parent term exist if passed
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $parentexist
     */
    private function parentExist()
    {
        $parentExist = $this->args['parent'];

        if (    $parentExist > 0
             && !term_exists( (int) $parentExist ) 
        ) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( 
                sprintf(
                    __( 'Invalid parent ID supplied, no term exists with parent ID passed. Please add a valid parent ID' ),
                    __METHOD__
                )
            );
        }

        return $parentExist;
    }

    /**
     * Private method sanitizeTerm()
     *
     * Sanitize the term to insert
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $sanitizeTerm
     */
    private function sanitizeTerm()
    {
        $taxonomy              = $this->validateTaxonomy();
        $arguments             = $this->args;

        $arguments['taxonomy'] = $taxonomy;
        $arguments['name']     = $this->validateTerm();
        $arguments['parent']   = $this->parentExist();

        // Santize the term 
        $arguments = sanitize_term( $arguments, $taxonomy, 'db' );

        // Unslash name and description fields and cast parent to integer
        $arguments['name']        = wp_unslash( $arguments['name'] );
        $arguments['description'] = wp_unslash( $arguments['description'] );
        $arguments['parent']      = (int) $arguments['parent'];

        return (object) $arguments;
    }

    /**
     * Private method slug()
     *
     * Get or create a slug if no slug is set
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @return $slug
     */
    private function slug()
    {
        $term = $this->sanitizeTerm();
        $new_slug = $term->slug;
        if ( !$new_slug ) {
            $slug = sanitize_title( $term->name );
        } else {
            $slug = $new_slug;
        }

        return $slug;
    }

    /**
     * Public method addTerm()
     *
     * Add the term to db
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function addTerm()
    {
        $wpdb       = $this->wpdb();
        $term       = $this->sanitizeTerm();
        $taxonomy   = $term->taxonomy;
        $name       = $term->name;
        $parent     = $term->parent;
        $term_group = $term->term_group;

        $term_group = 0;

        if ( $term->alias_of ) {
            $alias = get_term_by( 
                'slug', 
                $term->alias_of, 
                $term->taxonomy 
            );
            if ( !empty( $alias->term_group ) ) {
                // The alias we want is already in a group, so let's use that one.
                $term_group = $alias->term_group;
            } elseif ( ! empty( $alias->term_id ) ) {
                /*
                 * The alias is not in a group, so we create a new one
                 * and add the alias to it.
                 */
                $term_group = $wpdb->get_var(
                    "SELECT MAX(term_group) 
                    FROM $wpdb->terms"
                ) + 1;

                wp_update_term( 
                    $alias->term_id, 
                    $this->args['taxonomy'], 
                    [
                        'term_group' => $term_group,
                    ] 
                );
            }
        }

        $slug = wp_unique_term_slug( 
            $this->slug(), 
            $term
        );

        if ( false === $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->terms, compact( 'name', 'slug', 'term_group' ) ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'db_insert_error', __( 'Could not insert term into the database' ), $wpdb->last_error );
        }

        $term_id = (int) $wpdb->insert_id;

        // Seems unreachable, However, Is used in the case that a term name is provided, which sanitizes to an empty string.
        if ( empty( $slug ) ) {
            $slug = sanitize_title( 
                $slug, 
                $term_id 
            );

            /** This action is documented in wp-includes/taxonomy.php */
            do_action( 'edit_terms', $term_id, $taxonomy );
            $wpdb->update( $wpdb->terms, compact( 'slug' ), compact( 'term_id' ) );

            /** This action is documented in wp-includes/taxonomy.php */
            do_action( 'edited_terms', $term_id, $taxonomy );
        }

        $tt_id = $wpdb->get_var( 
            $wpdb->prepare( "
                SELECT tt.term_taxonomy_id 
                FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt 
                INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms AS t 
                ON tt.term_id = t.term_id 
                WHERE tt.taxonomy = %s 
                AND t.term_id = %d
            ", 
            $taxonomy, 
            $term_id 
            ) 
        );

        if ( !empty($tt_id) ) {
            return [
                'term_id'          => $term_id, 
                'term_taxonomy_id' => $tt_id
            ];
        }

        $wpdb->insert( 
            $wpdb->term_taxonomy, 
            compact( 'term_id', 'taxonomy', 'description', 'parent') + ['count' => 0] 
        );
        $tt_id = (int) $wpdb->insert_id;


        /**
         * Fires immediately after a new term is created, before the term cache is cleaned.
         *
         * @since 2.3.0
         *
         * @param int    $term_id  Term ID.
         * @param int    $tt_id    Term taxonomy ID.
         * @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy slug.
         */
        do_action( "create_term", $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );

        /**
         * Fires after a new term is created for a specific taxonomy.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$taxonomy`, refers
         * to the slug of the taxonomy the term was created for.
         *
         * @since 2.3.0
         *
         * @param int $term_id Term ID.
         * @param int $tt_id   Term taxonomy ID.
         */
        do_action( "create_$taxonomy", $term_id, $tt_id );

        /**
         * Filter the term ID after a new term is created.
         *
         * @since 2.3.0
         *
         * @param int $term_id Term ID.
         * @param int $tt_id   Taxonomy term ID.
         */
        $term_id = apply_filters( 'term_id_filter', $term_id, $tt_id );

        clean_term_cache($term_id, $taxonomy);

        /**
         * Fires after a new term is created, and after the term cache has been cleaned.
         *
         * @since 2.3.0
         *
         * @param int    $term_id  Term ID.
         * @param int    $tt_id    Term taxonomy ID.
         * @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy slug.
         */
        do_action( 'created_term', $term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy );

        /**
         * Fires after a new term in a specific taxonomy is created, and after the term
         * cache has been cleaned.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$taxonomy`, refers to the taxonomy slug.
         *
         * @since 2.3.0
         *
         * @param int $term_id Term ID.
         * @param int $tt_id   Term taxonomy ID.
         */
        do_action( "created_$taxonomy", $term_id, $tt_id );

        return [
            'term_id'          => $term_id, 
            'term_taxonomy_id' => $tt_id
        ];      
    }
}
```

You can then use it as follow:

```
$q = new WPInsertTerm( 'My Term', 'category', ['parent' => 1] );
$q->addTerm();
```

Here we add our term, `My Term` to the parent term with ID `1` in build in taxonomy `category`.

Note, running this 100 times will add 100 terms called `My Term` under parent term `1`.

### ADDITIONAL NOTES

- With the above, everything term name related queries should be avoided

  - By default, there are already an issue with term names in a `tax_query` in `WP_Query`. This class addition would make the use of the `name` field absolutely impossible
  - Getting terms by name should also be avoided at all costs as the wrong term will in all probability be returned.

A final note, having several terms with the same name will be very very confusing and might open a few cans of rotten worms, so you will need to be absolutely sure that this is what you want

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

[`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) is quite a busy function with a lot of stuff that goes on before a term is successfully added to a taxonomy.

The first important section is this:

```
$slug_provided = ! empty( $args['slug'] );
if ( ! $slug_provided ) {
    $slug = sanitize_title( $name );
} else {
    $slug = $args['slug'];
}
```

In short, what this means is, if you haven't explicitly set a slug, a slug will be created from the name given via the [`santitize_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) function. This is the basis which will decide whether a term will be added or not as the slug is the important part moving forward.

So if we would want to insert a term with the name `My Term`, we would end up with a slug like `my-term` if we did not set a slug.

The next important part is this: (*Which runs regardless if slug being where set or not*)

```
/*
 * Prevent the creation of terms with duplicate names at the same level of a taxonomy hierarchy,
 * unless a unique slug has been explicitly provided.
 */
$name_matches = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'name' => $name,
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

/*
 * The `name` match in `get_terms()` doesn't differentiate accented characters,
 * so we do a stricter comparison here.
 */
$name_match = null;
if ( $name_matches ) {
    foreach ( $name_matches as $_match ) {
        if ( strtolower( $name ) === strtolower( $_match->name ) ) {
            $name_match = $_match;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`$name` (*$name = wp_unslash( $args['name'] );*) which is the name you have explicitely set is used to return all terms with a name matching `$name` to compare to the term you are trying to insert, if there are any. If there are any terms that exists by `$name`, a more exact match is done to match terms.

As the description/docblock says *`get_terms()` doesn't differentiate accented characters*, so we might end up with terms having names like `my Term` and `My terM`. All letters are set to lower in this match, so all term names are set to `my term` for matching. This makes sense, because if those terms (*or any of the returned terms*) were created (*either back end or front end or programmically*) without having a slug set, names like `my Term` and `My terM` and our term `My Term` would all produce the same slug, `my-term`, so we would need elimanate such issues.

The last important section here before a unique slug is created and the term inserted, is the following section

```
if ( $name_match ) {
    $slug_match = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug, $taxonomy );
    if ( ! $slug_provided || $name_match->slug === $slug || $slug_match ) {
        if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy ) ) {
            $siblings = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'get' => 'all', 'parent' => $parent ) );

            $existing_term = null;
            if ( $name_match->slug === $slug && in_array( $name, wp_list_pluck( $siblings, 'name' ) ) ) {
                $existing_term = $name_match;
            } elseif ( $slug_match && in_array( $slug, wp_list_pluck( $siblings, 'slug' ) ) ) {
                $existing_term = $slug_match;
            }

            if ( $existing_term ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'term_exists', __( 'A term with the name provided already exists with this parent.' ), $existing_term->term_id );
            }
        } else {
            return new WP_Error( 'term_exists', __( 'A term with the name provided already exists in this taxonomy.' ), $name_match->term_id );
        }
    }
}
```

This section only runs when we have positively identified any other term with the same name as the one we would like to insert. Again, this section runs regardless whther a slug has been set or not.

The first thing that this section do is to return any matching term from db which matches our slug from the term we would want to insert which comes from the first section of code in the answer. Our slug is `my-term`. [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) either return a term object if there is a term that already in db which matches the term by slug of the term we would want to insert, or false if there is no term that already matches our term by slug.

Now a lot of check is done here, the first is a condition that runs the following checks

- Check if we have explicitely set a slug (`! $slug_provided`), return true if haven't
- If the slug from a matching term (*from the second block of code in this answer*) matches the slug from the term we want to insert (*in this case `my-term`*). Retruns true if there is a match
- Whether we have a term object returned from `get_term_by()`.

If any of these three conditions return true, a check is then done to check if our taxonomy is hierarchical. If this returns false, ie, our taxonomy is non hierarchical like tags, the following error is returned:

> A term with the name provided already exists in this taxonomy.

quite obviously as we cannot have terms with the same name in a non hierarchical taxonomy.

If this returns true, ie our taxonomy is hierarchical, all sibling terms is queried by parent (*which will be either `0` or whatever integer value we have explicitely set*).

`wp_insert_term()` now do its final check before deciding to go ahead with inserting the term or not. A failure here would throw the error message you are refering to in your question

> A term with the name provided already exists with this parent

This is what the final check does:

All the direct child terms are queried from db from the given taxonomy and parent (*which is either `0` or the value specified by you*). Remember that we are still inside the condition which states that there are terms matching the name of the term we want to insert. Two checks are done on the returned array of child categories:

- The first check involves the following: The term's slug from the matched term `$name_match` are checked against the slug from our term, `my-term` (*remember this comes from block one of code in the answer*). Also, our term name that we have set, `My Term` are checked against all names from the direct children from our parent.
- The second check is the following: A check is done to see if there was a term returned by `get_term_by()` and if the slug from the first block of code in this answer matches any slugs from the direct children from the parent term.

If any of these conditions returns true, the

> A term with the name provided already exists with this parent.

error message is thrown and the term is not inserted. A false will in all probably lead to the term successfully being created and inserted.

Now we can look at your question

> Why should the name be unique, don't understand as the slug is.

You can have duplicate names within a hierarchical taxonomy if, and **only if**

- There are no term with a matching name on the same level in the hierarchy. So any two top level terms, or any two direct children from the same parent term cannot have the same name. This line:

  ```
  if ( $name_match->slug === $slug && in_array( $name, wp_list_pluck( $siblings, 'name' ) ) )
  ```

  of code prohibits that.
- You can have the same names for terms in a hierarchical taxonomy if the term is in one top level parent, a child to that top level parent and one grandchild to that specific child, if and **only if** their slugs are unique. This line

  ```
  elseif ( $slug_match && in_array( $slug, wp_list_pluck( $siblings, 'slug' ) ) )
  ```

  prohibits terms with the same name having the same slug

You cannot have terms with the same name in a non hierarchical taxonomy as they do not have parent/child type relationships

So, if you are sure your taxonomy is hierarchical, and you slug is unique, it still does not mean you can have the same name, as you need to take parent into consideration. If your parent remain the same, regardless of unique slug being set, your term will not be inserted and will throw the error message you are seeing

### POSSIBLE WORKAROUND TO MAKE NAME UNIQUE

The best will be to write a wrapper function where you use the same logic as `wp_insert_term()` to first check if there are already a term with the same name with the same parent, and if so, take the name and run some kind of function on the name to make it unique.

I would encourage you to take all the logic in this answer, use it in a custom wrapper function to create a unique name, and play around with ideas. If you get stuck, feel free to post waht you have in a new question, and I'll be happy to take a look at it when I have time.

Best of luck

Comment: great, very informative description of the process.

Comment: @PieterGoosen ! Thanks a lot, i will take a look on this tomorrow.
Very complete and detailed process ;)

Comment: One idea would be to run the slug first through `$slug = wp_unique_term_slug( $slug, $term );`  before it's used in `wp_insert_term( $slug, $taxonomy, ... )`. Here we would need `$term` as an object, e.g.  `$term = new stdClass;` with `$term->taxonomy = $taxonomy`; etc.

Comment: @birgire we must be careful with term names and creating unique slugs too early. We can end up with 100 terms on 100 page loads if we accidently run the process wrongly ;-)

Comment: yes,  that kind of *brute-term-forcing* should only be used wisely in a controlled situation ;-)

Comment: @birgire You can create terms with duplicate names within the same hierarchy, Ripleys believe it or not ;-). About to finish tests, will post my code tonight. Must warn you, it is dirty and might be a real [*Part Deux*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=part+deux)

Comment: ups! really sorry about that phrase usage here, I didn't realized there where different negative meanings of it - only meant "part two" ;-) (so I deleted that comment)

Comment: @birgire Hahaha, I know you meant *part two*, was just joking around ;-). As for the solution to the OP's question to have terms with the same name, my addition-to-come might actually be described as the negative part of *Part Deux*, hahahaha, and that is actually what I was playing on. You actually gave me quite an idea as heading for the edit, *Part Deux or Part Deux - The Dirty Sequal*

Comment: hehe I'm warming up the popcorn  for the sequel *The Term Saga Continues...* ;-)

Comment: @birgire I might not post tonight, it is my son's b/day, so I'm going to braai tonight. Your title deserves an almagation with mine, can make an interesting title ;-)

Comment: Congratulation with your son's birthday, I hope you two have a great evening. Cheers. My daughters recently celebrated their (same, not twins) birthday ;-)

Comment: @Polykrom see my update, hope this will help you. Please read everything carefully before jumping in and running the code

Comment: @birgire squized in some time to post the code. Hope it will help the OP. Of to braai now. *same, not twins) birthday* Congrats to them, and to your timing ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Woow , nice piece of code... Have to test it a little more , don't know if i will use this Class , but it could help if i need a way to extend the core functions !
Thanks a lot ! Gr8 stuff ;)

Comment: @Polykrom Thanks for the feedback. The code I supplied is for you to modify, use, abuse or not-to-use as you like. At the end this was all just a challenge to show that you can coax the system and have duplicate term names ;-). I don't know if you ever going to use my code fully or if you are going to make full use of duplicate names, but if you ever hit a ditch somewhere because of duplicate names, drop me a comment, would like to know about that. As I said, I cannot test thois fully on my local install, so there might be issues in future that I have missed now. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 1):

After @PieterGoosen advices, i figure out my issue, here is the complete function that check if a term name already exists in a Taxonomy.

It doesn't provide yet a name substitution if name already exists in the parent term.

I don't need to check for the slug as i've let WP create one automatically for me.

```
function check_term_name($term_name,$taxonomy,$parent) 
{

$name_matches = get_terms( $taxonomy, array(
    'name' => $term_name,
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );


$name_match = null;
if ( $name_matches ) {
    foreach ( $name_matches as $_match ) {
        if ( strtolower( $term_name ) === strtolower( $_match->name ) ) {
            $name_match = $_match;
            break;
        }
    }
}


if ( $name_match ) {

    if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy ) ) {
        $siblings = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'get' => 'all', 'parent' => $parent->term_id ) );
        $existing_term = null;
        if ( in_array( $term_name, wp_list_pluck( $siblings, 'name' ) ) ) {
            $existing_term = $name_match;
        }

        if ( $existing_term ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'term_exists', __( 'A term with the name provided already exists with this parent.' ), $existing_term->term_id );
        }
    } else {
        return new WP_Error( 'term_exists', __( 'A term with the name provided already exists in this taxonomy.' ), $name_match->term_id );
    }

}


return $term_name;

}
```

I wonder if it wouldn't possible to add a custom meta to the term (new in WP 4.4) with the original name in place of the name property of the term.
So i could add a unique id to the term name and create a category selector which display the custom meta in place of the name.

```
add_term_meta($term_id,'name',$name);
```

and retrieve it to populate my selector :

```
get_term_meta($term_id,'name');
```

### EDIT

I've put my hands in the

```
add_term_meta
```

and put together the suggestions you can find [here](http://themehybrid.com/weblog/introduction-to-wordpress-term-meta)

So , if we want to have the same name even if term name is different, we have to add a custom meta 'real_name' to the term.

So first, we register the meta :

```
add_action( 'init', 'blaamy_register_meta' );

function blaamy_register_meta() {

    register_meta( 'term', 'real_name' );

}
```

then we add a new column to our taxonomy, say we have a object_category taxonomy :

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-object_category_columns', 'blaamy_edit_term_columns' );

function blaamy_edit_term_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns['real_name'] = __( 'Real Name', 'blaamy' );

    return $columns;
}
```

Now we need to manage the custom column :

```
add_filter( 'manage_object_category_custom_column', 'blaamy_manage_term_custom_column', 10, 3 );

function blaamy_manage_term_custom_column( $out, $column, $term_id ) {

    if('real_name' === $column){

        $real_name = blaamy_get_term_real_name( $term_id, true );

        if ( ! $real_name )
            $real_name = '';

        $out = sprintf( '<span class="real_name-block">%s</span>', esc_attr( $real_name ));


    }

    return $out;
}
```

We need also something to get the real_name meta value :

```
function blaamy_get_term_real_name( $term_id, $hash = false ) {

    $real_name = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'real_name', true );

    return $real_name;
}
```

Now we create the real name form field :

```
add_action( 'object_category_add_form_fields', 'blaamy_new_term_real_name_field' );

function blaamy_new_term_real_name_field() {

    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'blaamy_term_real_name_nonce' ); ?>

    <div class="form-field blaamy-term-real-name-wrap">
        <label for="blaamy-term-real-name">Real Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="blaamy_term_real_name" id="blaamy_term_real_name" value="" class="blaamy-real-name-field" data-default-real-name="" />
    </div>
<?php }
```

and then we have to create the real name edit form field :

```
add_action( 'object_category_edit_form_fields', 'blaamy_edit_term_real_name_field' );

function blaamy_edit_term_real_name_field( $term ) {

    $default = "";
    $real_name   = blaamy_get_term_real_name( $term->term_id, true );

    if ( ! $author )
        $real_name = $real_name; ?>

    <tr class="form-field blaamy-term-real-name-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="blaamy-term-real-name">Real Name</label></th>
        <td>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'blaamy_term_real_name_nonce' ); ?>
            <input type="text" name="blaamy_term_real_name" id="blaamy-term-real-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $real_name ); ?>"  data-default-real-name="<?php echo esc_attr( $default ); ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```

and finally the real name create and update functions :

```
add_action( 'edit_object_category',   'blaamy_save_term_real_name' );
add_action( 'create_object_category', 'blaamy_save_term_real_name' );

function blaamy_save_term_real_name( $term_id ) {

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['blaamy_term_real_name_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['blaamy_term_real_name_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    $old_real_name = blaamy_get_term_real_name( $term_id );
    $new_real_name = isset( $_POST['blaamy_term_real_name'] ) ? $_POST['blaamy_term_real_name'] : '';

    if ( $old_real_name && '' === $new_real_name )
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, 'real_name' );

    else if ( $old_real_name !== $new_real_name )
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'real_name', $new_real_name );
}
```

We have just to create a combobox or anything else on frontend which is populated by our real_name meta !

Comment: Just one question regarding a comment to your question. Say you have two terms with identical names, like `My Term`, what will be an alternative to the second one, because the easiest would be `My Term 001`. We can also have an array of names to append, like `['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'etc']` where we allow up to maybe 5 variations and throw an error after that. We then monitor and add a name from the array. Say `My Term` is the third variation, our name would be `My Term Name 3`. Please reply with exact requirements as this is quite crucial

Comment: @PieterGoosen , well your suggestion doesn't fit my requirement, i need to have the same name in my Selector. It would not be very user friendly and readable to have all this different variations. So i think that the solution with `add_term_meta($term_id,'name',$name)` is the best for me. Btw thaks a lot for your help ;)

Comment: OK, great. So if I understand you correctly, if a term exist with the same name in the same hierarchy, you will not insert a new term, but extra term meta

Comment: It does seem that we will be able to have duplicate names regardless of hierarchy. I'm still busy with the class, but it looks promising. Will see what my tests say. Holding thumbs

Comment: @PieterGoosen , yes , we can have the same names in Hierarchy but not in the same parent. So my suggestion is interesting in the case we need the same name into one taxonomy term. Thanks to have duplicated my answer ! Cheers ;)

Comment: You can, I have done it on local install. I need to run a final test or two on my code, then I will post the code

Comment: ok @PieterGoosen .. can't wait to see your solution ;) Let me known !